# Find total number of times a number appears in two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database where I add soccer games shown on TV. Each team is represented as an number. I can't really figure out how I can make a query to list how many times a team has been shown on TV, no matter if they played at home or away.

I'm trying to make a top 20 list of teams thats been shown on TV. The two columns I have team id in are called "hjemmehold" and "udehold" (it's danish :)).

Anyone can help me here?

Comment: `UNION` + `COUNT` + `DISTINCT`

Comment: Can you tell us how your tables are set up/ rows/columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Team, Count(*)
FROM (select Away as Team from Games union all select Home as Team from Games) t
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY Count(*) Desc
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: This worked perfekt with a little edit to fit my needs ... this is the code i used

SELECT Team, Count(*) FROM (select udehold as Team from kampe WHERE dato <= 
'$today' union all select hjemmehold as Team from kampe WHERE dato <= 
'$today') d GROUP BY Team ORDER BY Count(*) Desc LIMIT 20

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Away)+SUM(Home) AS NumGames
FROM Games
WHERE Team=@Team
```

Obviously this is pseudocode, but put the proper tables/fields/params in and you should be good to go.

For all 20 teams:

```
SELECT TOP 20 Team, SUM(Away)+SUM(Home) AS NumGames
FROM Games
ORDER BY SUM(Away)+SUM(Home) desc
```

Comment: This works for obtaining total games played by one team, but not for ranking a list of the top 20.

Answer (score 0):

t.his should be able to give you the top 20 teams that have played.  This will also allow you to find which teams have not yet played a game (if you remove the top 20 part).

```
SELECT TOP 20
    team_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM GAMES WHERE HOME = t.team_id) + (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM GAMES WHERE AWAY = team_id) AS team_count
FROM TEAMS T 
ORDER BY team_count DESC
```